# How to properly add a Commerce Shipping Service option via AJAX during checkout

Tags: 7, ajax, commerce

- I have the `Payment` and `Shipping service` block in the same
  checkout pane.
- I update the Shipping service block with AJAX when
  selecting a Payment method, as available Shipping services depend on
  the selected Payment method.

But once the Shipping service block is reloaded, if I select another Shipping service and submit the form, I will be redirected to the initial pane as if my selection was unvalid - with no error message.

This is the code I use to update the Shipping services block, after saving the order to update the available Shipping services. (Inspired by [some other posts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/143958/commerce-checkout-update-cart-pane-after-user-select-a-shipping-option-ajax))

And I can't find a way to make the Shipping selection work on submit after being reloaded via AJAX.

- Should I also update the form state?
- `commerce_shipping_service_rate_order($service, $order)` didn't change
  anything
- Nor `commerce_shipping_pane_service_details_refresh($form,
  $form_state)`

Would someone have an idea what could go wrong?

```
/**
 * Alter checkout shipping form.
 */
function mymodule_checkout_shipping_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Replace AJAX callback by a custom one.
    $form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']['#ajax']['callback'] = 'mymodule_payment_pane_checkout_form_details_refresh';
}


/**
 * Checkout shipping pane AJAX callback function.
 */
function mymodule_payment_pane_checkout_form_details_refresh($form, &$form_state) {
    // Commands initialization.
    $commands = array();
    // Load the current order
    $order_id = $form_state['order']->order_id;
    $order = commerce_order_load($order_id);

    // Set the newly selected payment option to the order
    $order->data['payment_method'] = $form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']['#default_value'];
    // Refresh the current order (more specific: update it's line items
    commerce_cart_order_refresh($order);
    // save the refreshed order (more specific: recalculate the order total and save it)
    commerce_order_save($order);

    // Default Commerce AJAX callback for the payment pane.
    $commerce_wrapper = '#' . $form_state['triggering_element']['#ajax']['wrapper'];
    $commerce_output = commerce_payment_pane_checkout_form_details_refresh($form, $form_state);
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace($commerce_wrapper, render($commerce_output));

    // Update Commerce shipping pane.
    $panes = commerce_checkout_panes();
    $shipping_pane = drupal_get_form('commerce_shipping_pane_checkout_form', $panes['commerce_shipping'], $order);
    $form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_rates'] = $shipping_pane['shipping_rates'];
    $form['commerce_shipping']['shipping_service'] = $shipping_pane['shipping_service'];
    $form['commerce_shipping']['service_details'] = $shipping_pane['service_details'];
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#commerce-shipping-service-ajax-wrapper', drupal_render($form['commerce_shipping']));

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Stackexchange does not allow me to comment, did you find a solution? I am experiencing exactly the same issue. Thanks.