# Fee line item added programatically being removed from order after checkout submit

Tags: commerce, ajax

I am attempting to add a fee programatically based on the payment method selected by the user by calling some `commerce_fees` functions in an Ajax callback attached to a custom payment method field. This is a single page checkout and so this functionality is essential.

The custom fee line item does seem to be added successfully, at least in the updated cart summary view, but temporarily.

[image: custom fee added after ajax cart refresh]

I say temporarily for two reasons:

1. After the checkout page is submitted and the completed order is viewed, no trace of the fee remains (the total is $400 again and a price of only $400 was sent to the payment gateway).
2. When I `dpm` the `$order` (after refreshing the page) the only indication that the fee is indeed being added somewhere is that the `commerce_order_total...['price']['components']` array contains the custom fee.  The only item in the `commerce_line_items` array is the original product.

I am attempting this programatically because, while I could obtain the same fee-adding functionality with the Rules module, I faced a somewhat similar issue of the fee being deleted immediately after checkout submission, only to be reapplied *after* the payment was processed by the third-party payment gateway.  That frustrated me to no end and so I thought by adding the fees manually they would stick.

Here's my custom module code, utilizing a hodge-podge of some `commerce_fees` functions along with `hook_commerce_cart_order_refresh`.

I utilized some of the logic explained in this question: [Commerce checkout - Update cart pane after user select a shipping option (ajax)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/143958/53314).

```
function single_page_checkout_payment_surcharge_refresh($form, &$form_state) {

  // Get order from form
  list($order, $checkout_pane) = $form_state['build_info']['args'];

  // Load up to date order
  $order = commerce_order_load($order->order_id);

  // Get selected payment method
  $payment_method = $form['field_payment_methods']['und']['#value'];

  // Set new default value in case of page refresh
  $form['field_payment_methods']['und']['#default_value'] = $payment_method;

  // Set the selected payment method
  $order->field_payment_methods['und'][0]['value'] = $payment_method;

  // Wrap order for hook_checkout_commerce_cart_order_refresh
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

  /**
  * Implements hook_commerce_cart_order_refresh().
  *
  * Remove any existing commerce custom fee line item.
  */
  function singe_page_checkout_commerce_cart_order_refresh($order_wrapper) {
    $line_item_ids = array();

    foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
      // If the line item is a fee remove it.
      if ($line_item_wrapper->getBundle() == 'fee') {
        // Delete the line item, and remove it from the order.
        $line_item_ids[] = $line_item_wrapper->line_item_id->value();
        $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items->offsetUnset($delta);
      }
    }

    // If we found any fee type line items...
    if (!empty($line_item_ids)) {
      // Then delete the line items.
      commerce_line_item_delete_multiple($line_item_ids);
    }

  }

  // delete existing line items with same id
  commerce_fees_delete_fee_line_item($order, $fee, TRUE);

  switch ($payment_method) {

    case 'nmi_dp_cc|commerce_payment_nmi_dp_cc':
      $fee = 'cc_surcharge';
      $base_rate = $order->commerce_order_total['und'][0]['data']['components'][0]['price'];
      $base_rate['amount'] = $base_rate['amount'] * 0.04;
      break;

    case 'nmi_dp_echeck|commerce_payment_nmi_dp_echeck':
      $fee = 'check_processing';
      $base_rate = $order->commerce_order_total['und'][0]['data']['components'][0]['price'];
      $base_rate['amount'] = 150;
      break;
  }

  $base_rate['data'] = commerce_price_component_add($base_rate, $fee, $base_rate, TRUE, FALSE);

  // Create new fee line item with the base_rate decided by the fee type
  $line_item = commerce_fees_line_item_new($fee, $base_rate, $order->order_id);

  // Save and add the line item to the order.
  $new_line_item = commerce_fees_add_fee_line_item($line_item, $order, FALSE);

  // Save the order
  commerce_order_save($order);

  // Update checkout cart review
  list($view_id, $display_id) = explode('|', variable_get('commerce_cart_contents_pane_view', 'commerce_cart_summary|default'));

  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.view-commerce-cart-summary', commerce_embed_view($view_id, $display_id, array($order->order_id)));

  $commands[] = ajax_command_after('.main form', theme('status_messages'));

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

A side issue is also that this Ajax call seems to take a good while to fully execute, because if I select another payment method too soon, the existing fee(s) are not properly removed, and so fees begin to stack.

NOTE: **I am fully aware of the need to alert the user of the surcharge and that some payment gateways do not allow it.**